# SharePoint & PowerApps Forms ... Auto fill list field by retrieving Data from 2nd list

Tags: powerapps

I have 2 lists in SharePoint.... List 1: Request List & List 2: Approver List.


User selects new and PowerApps form displays where the employee enters his request.

**Request List** fields...
Leave Date(Date field) 
 
Employee(Person field)  
Department (Text)
Approver (Person field "AutoFill")*

* Once employee enters their name in the Request form I want the form to lookup his Approver in List 2 and then prefill the Approver field.

**Approver List** fields.....
Employee (Person field)
Approving Manager (Person field)
Department (Text)

Can someone suggest a good way to make this work.  Lookups and Cascading lookups not the solution.

### Thanks for reading my post... any help is appreciated.

Carlos... 
Here are some screen shots of the configuration....

[PowerApps setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxHJ8.png)

[Effects after adding suggested code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv4Z5.png)

Answer (score 1):

A lookup is a solution for this, but in PowerApps, not in SharePoint. Here's how you would go about implementing this:

- On the RequestList list on SharePoint, select the "PowerApps -> Customize forms" option that will bring you to the form in the PowerApps Studio (web editor).
- Add a new data source (in the ribbon, View -> Data sources -> Add data source), that references the ApproverList list on the same SharePoint site
- Select the card that represents the approver field in the list (it will likely be called `Approver_DataCard1` or something similar)
- In the right-side pane, select the 'Advanced' tab, and click the padlock that says "Unlock to change properties"

Now we can start updating the properties that will perform the lookup. Click the "More options" button to show all properties of the card, and search for `Default`. Set its value to

```
If
    IsBlank(DataCardValue3.Selected),
    Blank(),
    LookUp(
        ApproverList,
        Employee.Email = DataCardValue3.Selected.Email,
        ApprovingManager))
```

Where `DataCardValue3` is the name of the control (a combo box control) that is used to select the employee for who the request is being made.

Now every time the employee is changed, it will look at the ApproverList on SharePoint for an employee whose e-mail is the same as the one for the selected employee.

If you don't want to give the form user the option to override the default approver, you can also update the `DisplayMode` property of the data card for the approver to `DisplayMode.View` so that it will only show the approver to the user, without letting them change it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback Carlos... when I get to work tomorrow I will give it a try and let you know my results... again thanks!

Comment: Hey Carlos.. I followed your example and it did not work.  It does not fill in the Approving Managers name, you have to click the combo box button and it just shows a selection list (item1, item 2, item 3, ....etc).  I have screen shots but don't believe that I can share them here.  I am also getting a Delegation warning message that the Lookup part might not work correctly on large data sets.

Comment: Carlos - I added two pictures to the original post above click the links to see the issue.